External IP answering DHCP requests
Testing the DHCP with "DHCP Find Version 1.2" and leaving it open for some time, it shows DHCP offers from an external / public IP. How is this even possible? We use a network within 192.168.#. The two offered IPs are within the correct range. However 105.109.115.46 should not exist. The DCs don't have any interfaces on this IP. Both offered IPs are reserved, so that I can't tell if new leases have been granted by the production DCs.
Packet from 105.109.115.46 
 Offered IP 192.168.#.* 
 Renew Due in 1296000 Seconds
 Lease Length 2592000 Seconds
 Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
-------------------------
Packet from 105.109.115.46 
 Offered IP 192.168.#.** 
 Renew Due in 1296000 Seconds
 Lease Length 2592000 Seconds
 Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0

Additional info:
For some time now our DHCP has been behaving strangely. For example, we had a blackout 2 weeks ago. When we restarted the servers, the DHCP had reservations that had been changed years ago. Some of the hardware doesn't even exist anymore. New devices that have been added a few weeks ago have disappeared. The DHCP scopes have been replicated before the blackout. But the second DHCP had the same settings after the reboot. When I reboot them oneat a time, they don't lose the config.
Where could the servers get the old settings from?

Is 105.109.115.46 one of your IP addresses in general? Have you checked which MAC address the offers come from?

"DHCP Find" is not a well known tool, so asking why it has certain behaviors won't lead to good answers. Are you enable to contact its vendor/original developer?

Your profile says you are from Germany, that IP address is from Algeria - so, yeah, that is odd
